# Installation of vue-cli : how does it work?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

I'm very new to Node Package Manager and also Vue, and I'm trying to understand what exactly is going on with using the Vue CLI.

The vue.js website has this as instructions for running the official Vue CLI:

[image]

I have a few questions about this:

1. Does `npm install --global vue-cli` need to be executed only once on a machine, or once on a directory, or once per new project you're starting? In other words, once it's on your computer, is that the last time you need to run that command, or do you need to execute this command every single new project you start?
2. Once a new project is initiated, are local copies of the newest version of vue (and vue-router, if selected) installed?
3. If I finish this project and want to deploy it, how do I then port this over to a production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once in a machine, except for the rare cases where one is isolating one's `npm` install (such as by using `nodeenv` or inside a container); that's what the `global` option is for.
2. After running `npm install`, yes.
3. Running `npm run build` and copying the contents of the resulting `dist` directory to the production machine (often within a `/var/www` directory or similar). This can be automated further in many ways.